# Cannot count # of occurances where X and Y are true

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to create a script that will count the number of occurances of Keyboard requests, but also filter them by a specific building. As the building mentioned is in the same sheet, I wanted to use that. However, I am facing some issues. Please help!

```
=COUNTIFS('Form Responses 1'!C2:C10000 ,"Keyboard" ,'Form Responses 1'!B2:B10000 "IKE")
```

I would like it to see if the B on that row is IKE and if the C in that row has Keyboard in it. However, whenever I try to run it, I get a parse error. Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a `,` in your formula, it should be:

`=COUNTIFS('Form Responses 1'!C2:C , "Keyboard" , 'Form Responses 1'!B2:B , "IKE")`

(also changed from `C2:C10000` to `C2:C`)